# NoReverseMatch Error - Everything looks ok in my urls.py what am I doing wrong

Tags: python, django

Have no idea what I'm doing wrong - and I swear it was working a few hours ago.

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('create', views.create, name='create'),
    path('<int:bet_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
    path('<int:bet_id>/wager/', views.wager, name='wager'),
]
```

this is the link the html template:
a href ="{% url 'wager' bet.id %}"

views.py:

```
def wager(request, bet_id):
    bet = get_object_or_404(Bet, pk=bet_id)
    return render (request, 'bets/wager.html', {'bet':bet})
```

And here's the error (6 is the specific bet_id for this case)

```
NoReverseMatch at /bets/6/wager/
Reverse for 'wager' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['bets/(?P<bet_id>[0-9]+)/wager/$']
```

Comment: please post your html template code also

Comment: It says `with NO arguments not found`. Seems you are trying to open the page without arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Use **non overlapping** pattern in url configuration

```
path('wage_list', views.list_view, name='wage_list'),
path('wage_detail/<int:bet_id>/', views.wage_detail_view, name='wage_detail_view'),
```

and call in your list view as follows, which will take you to detail view

```
{% for obj in wage_list %}
<a href="{% url 'wage_detail_view' bet_id=obj.id %}">
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: hm this might work but i swear the logic and overlapping I had in place was worked earlier and nothing changed.  basically there are bets, someone selects a specific bet (/bet/<bet_id/) and then there is a wager on the specific bet (/bet/<bet_id>/wager)so i wanted to keep it in this order

Comment: thanks this might have worked but i just reloaded a previous version and its back to working again.  and I swear that it all looks identical.  maybe there was a bad indent somewhere or something.  thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

For me,

```py
bet = get_object_or_404(Bet, pk=bet_id)
```

It sounds like that the primary key for yor `Bet` object is named `bet_id`. May you consider changing `{% url 'wager' bet.id %}` to `{% url 'wager' bet.bet_id %}`?

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't work.  Primary key is Bet.id and I can confirm that i'm correctly passing it from the html <br>``` a href ="{% url 'wager' bet.id %}"```` to the views.py <br> def wager(request, bet_id): 
    *bet = get_object_or_404(Bet, pk=bet_id)*
    ***return render (request, 'bets/wager.html', {'bet':bet})*** <br> the bet line is correctly getting the object back, the issues is on the return render line

Answer (score 0):

**urls.py**:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('create', views.create, name='create'),
    path('<int:bet_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
    path('wager/<int:pk>', views.wager, name='wager'),
]
```

**views.py**:

```
def wager(request, bet_id):
    bet = get_object_or_404(Bet, pk=bet_id)
    return render (request, 'bets/wager.html', {'bet':bet})
```

**wager.html**:

```
<a href ="{% url 'wager' bet.id %}">Something</a>
```